MS Azure | Cannot create administrator account
I have setup an Azure account, but under users, I can only see my account and it is marked as member. I cannot change this to admin as I do not have permissions.
How can I grant admin permission to my account without having an admin account or the ability to create an account?

Member means that it's in the entra id directory. Admin is a role, not an account type. Azure generally uses rbac.

i have just setup an azure account - What does that mean exactly? You need to provide more details. Where did you crate this account? How did you create this account? How did you crate an account if you don't have an admin account?
